# Gaps when rendering function after rotating it

Tags: rendering, rotation

I'm rendering a sine function which renders fine with angle 0, but has gaps when rotating it. See pictures:

45º:

[image]

0º:

[image]

The values are generated with PHP. Each square picks up its status from the matrix generated with PHP.

```
for ($i = 4; $i < 125; $i++) {
    $angle = deg2rad(0);
    $x1 = $i;
    $y1 = round(8*sin($i/8),0)+50;

    $x = round($x1*cos($angle) - $y1*sin($angle),0);

    $y = round($x1*sin($angle) + $y1*cos($angle),0);

    if (($x > 1 and $x < 120) and ($y > 1 and $y < 120)){

        $this->mapArray[$x][$y]->set_value(1); // square rendered.
    }
}
```

I thought it had something to do with the round, but I use no rounding and also have the same results. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

you are rendering points and you want it to be curve. you are approximating curve with 121 points and there are ofcourse holes because it's length is bigger than 121 pixels.

what you need to do is to draw lines from last point to the next. it will still be approximation, but you won't have gaps.

Answer (score 1):

This is only an idea, that would need a further elaboration. Suppose that the curve is drawn from left to right and from top to bottom. We could remember the last pixel (x0, y0) that was set. When drawing the pixel (x, y), there is no gap before (x, y) if (x0, y0) is one of the pixels (x-1, y), (x, y-1), (x-1, y-1). If it is not the case, then there is a gap between (x0, y0) and (x, y). This gap can be filled by interpolation. If only one pixel is missing, then it can be set by a case analysis. If the distance between the pixels (x0, y0) and (x, y) is larger, then an interpolating line could be drawn between them using the [Bresenham's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm).